# How to run JUnit tests in an Android runtime?

Tags: java, android, maven, junit

The official JDK and the Android runtimes are fairly similar but support different sets of classes. For example, the `java.awt` package is unavailable on Android, and the `android` packages are unavailable in the JDK.

In order to write a Java library that functions in both regular Java and Android, it would be desirable to run the JUnit tests inside both VMs. Is there a way to do this, such as using a Maven plugin? Or is there a different approach that's recommended?

Answer (score 1):

Unit tests executed on an Android device/emulator - or "[Instrumented Unit Tests](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/instrumented-unit-tests)" as they are called can be developed using Android Studio / Gradle.

I am not sure if and how Instrumented Unit Tests can be performed directly with Maven.

One possible way would be to execute Gradle from within Maven using [gradle-maven-plugin](https://github.com/LendingClub/gradle-maven-plugin).

Comment: any updates on this?